# Test if one GameObject is above another with any shape colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Essentially, I have a function designed to test if one object is positioned entirely above another while taking the collider bounds into account:

```
public static bool isAbove(GameObject a, GameObject b)
{
    Collider2D colliderA = a.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    Collider2D colliderB = b.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    return a.transform.position.y - (colliderA.bounds.size.y * 0.5) >= b.transform.position.y + (colliderB.bounds.size.y * 0.5);
}
```

When I originally wrote this, I had no intention to use bounding shapes other than boxes, so the algorithm worked. Now, I am using a circle collider on one of the objects and a box collider on the other one, which makes the algorithm inconsistent, as it's still treating the circle as a box. I really want this working for any shape colliders in any combination.

I thought that I could specify a point directly below the first object and then find the max point at that x position, but I can't find this option anywhere, and I'm still not sure if it's the solution I should be looking for.

Comment: Could you not just use `OnTriggerStay2D` and use the `Collision2D` data to determine if the objects are on top of one another?

Comment: @TEEBQNE How would I make use of the Collision2D data? I see that I can get the contact points of collision, but I don't see how that would be especially useful with comparing the actual positions of the objects.

Comment: You can get [`quite a lot more than contact points`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) from collision data. If the two objects are touching and you use the dot product, then it should be pretty clear. `Vector3.Dot(up, otherObject)` will give 0 if they are perfectly perpendicular, a value greater than 0 if the angle is less than 90º and a value less than 0 if the angle is greater than 90º. If you calculate the dot product between the up vector, and the vector to the other target, and the result is greater than 0 then the other target is above.

Comment: @TEEBQNE Your solution presented here worked for me. how can I mark it as the answer?

Comment: I can post it as a solution instead of a comment. You can accept that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, [`Collision2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) has a lot of useful information regarding the collision of two objects. Specifically for your use case, I would also look into the [`Vector3.Dot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html). To be brief, using `Vector3(up, otherObject` will give you a result to determine if two objects are over one another.

For a little more clarification, there are three possible cases that can be returned from `Vector3.Dot` and they are

1. **Dot is 0** - The two objects are perfectly perpendicular to one another
2. **Dot is <0** - The angle between the two objects is greater than 90º
3. **Dot is >0** - The angle between the two objects is less than 90º

For your specific use case, I would calculate the dot product between the up vector, and the vector to the other target. If the result is greater than 0 then the other target is above your current object. You can either only check this data when the objects are actively colliding or check it every frame. It would depend on how many objects you're checking against.

Answer (score 0):

This already exists anyway, you are looking for [`Collider2D.isTouching`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.IsTouching.html) so you simply do

```
return colliderA.isTouching(colliderB);
```

and done ;)

**However**, instead of passing in `GameObject` and everytime use `GetComponent` you should rather somewhere pre-cache the `Collider2D` references and directly use either

```
if(colliderA.isTouching(colliderB))
```

or also

```
if(Physics2D.isTouching(colliderA, colliderB))
```

They are more or less equivalent.

Comment: Does this check specifically if colliderA is on top? Reading the documentation, it seems to only check for contact unless you specify the second argument.

Comment: @Ptolemy2002 the second parameter is an **additional filter** .. without a filter you get more results than with the filter ;) .. you can e.g. say it shall only be true if both objects are on the same Z depth